# Express+Node.jsでGETリクエストしたユーザーのipアドレスを取得したい

Tags: javascript, node.js

1. タイトルの通り。GETリクエストしてきたユーザーのipアドレスを取得したいです。
2. 少し調べた結果、クッキーを使ってipアドレスを取得しようと思うのですがそれは正しい方法でしょうか。
   以上の2点について回答お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.ip`で良いかと思います。

- https://expressjs.com/ja/api.html#req.ip
- https://expressjs.com/ja/guide/behind-proxies.html

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send(`remote address: ${req.ip}`));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!"));
```

文脈が分かりませんが、cookiesは全く無関係だと思います。